# android drawText set width?

Tags: android, canvas, drawtext

Is there a way to draw text on the android with a set width.

I'm trying to draw text inside a box that is 300px wide. I want to set the text box to 300px and right align it. That way it lines up with the right side of the box.

I would set a default value for it, but the text wont always be the same and as the characters grow it wont be aligned anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an alternative approach: a label with wrap_content set placed within the box and specifying right-alignment. This may require some creative use of layouts, but I think it will be much more robust at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a TextView? Set the max width to 300px and go from there. I can see this working for anything but GL work.

Comment: I think he's wanting the text to always be exactly 300px wide, if I'm understanding correctly, resizing the text to accomodate no matter what the input.